# Access only for specific user

Tags: ravendb

I installed Ravendb 3.5 db as a windows service. Now I'm struggling to establish access to the Ravendb studio only to specific user. For that purpose I created user account ravendb and inside `Raven.Server.exe.config` I add following config lines

```
<add key="Raven/Authorization/Windows/RequiredUsers" value="ravendb"/>
<add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="None"/>
```

I tried to restart the ravendb service couple of times, even restarting machine but access is always granted.

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to RavenDB is *always* granted for:
* The administrator
* The user that is running the ravendb process.